# Same material, different results

Tags: materials

So I am building a scene, and I applied a simple gradient material to an object, and it wasn't behaving as expected, so I tried troubleshooting.

In the edit mode of the affected mesh, I added a plane, separated it, and applied all visual transforms.

Then I added a separate plane object and gave it the same material.
The new plane object behaved as expected with the material.

I can't figure out what's wrong with the object of the initial mesh that's causing the material to display incorrectly.

The two planes.

Original mesh with wrong shading on the left, and new plane with the expected result on the right

[image]

The shader graph

[image]

Comment: I think we'll need to see your Blend file. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page and then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

Comment: Some more information might be helpful - as @MarkusvonBroady shows in his answer, this can happen when you scale it in _Edit Mode_ and did not yet switch back to _Object Mode_ for the coordinates to be recalculated. But in your screenshot no objects seem to be selected and it is not apparent if any of those objects is in _Edit Mode_... so if the provided answer is not solving your problem, we definitely need more information what exactly is going on there (or even see the file as suggested).

Comment: It turns out it was probably a glitch in Blender. Blender ran out of memory and crashed. When I reopened the file, it somehow resolved itself. Thanks for the help 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you right-click on the *Gradient Texture* node, and choose *Online Manual* option, it will send you to the [documentation page](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.0/render/shader_nodes/textures/gradient.html?utm_source=blender-4.0.2#bpy-types-shadernodetexgradient) which says:

> **Vector**
>
> Texture coordinate to sample texture at; defaults to Generated texture coordinates if the socket is left unconnected.

*Generated* texture coordinate automatically adapts to the bounding box, to always have the minimum coordinate on each axis equal $0$, and maximum coordinate equal $1$, so it's just normalized coordinates. This is what you can see on the right plane, a gradient from $0$ to $1$.

I think the first plane is simply scaled in *Edit Mode* and hasn't yet had a chance to recalculate the coordinates, which will happen when you switch to *Object Mode*:

[image]